# Add a wIfi antenna on a Rapsberry Pi deployed underwater

Tags: wifi, video, streaming-video

I have Raspberry Pi in a pressure case that is deployed on the ocean floor and is collecting video. I would like to be able to communicate with the Pi from the surface without having to retrieve the entire system.

I know wifi can't transmit underwater, but is it possible to solder a wire on the Raspberry Pi board that could go from the Pi to the surface (say to a surface buoy) and would allow to receive wifi signal?

Comment: not really a Raspberry Pi specific question ... it belongs at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to show that it's a Raspberry Pi question. As it's written now, [it seems off-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). In the meantime, here's some things that might help: [a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=what+signals+propagate+underwater), and this article on [underwater rf propogation](https://www.hydro-international.com/content/article/underwater-electromagnetic-propagation).

Comment: Thanks. I edited my questions to hopefully clarify what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

No legal WiFi transmitter will be powerful enough to get the signal across 10 meters of salt water, no matter what antenna you use.

Deploying a 10 meter long coax cable to the antenna floating on the surface is theoretically possible. I would really consider using an Ethernet cable though, connecting to a router floating on the surface.

Comment: You could do the same thing with usb if it is less than 10ft.  Ethernet will get you 200m max, so that's probably better.  Also, probably easier to make it waterproof.

Comment: You can go longer on USB2 (in particular, 3 not so much) - with **active** extension leads. I believe you can use up to 5 x 16 feet, 4.88m USB2 leads which is 80 feet or over 24 meters - though as each extension will also draw power the amount available at the remote end will not be enough to power the RPi - so a separate (chunky!) power-supply cable (or a big battery) will also be needed to/in the depths. Also, of course, the joints in those USB leads will need to be properly enclosed/waterproofed!